# My model window is blinking while clicking button in bootstrap?Reason?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Below is my button code

Add Test Case

This is the script for model window.

```
$("#check_all").click(function(event) {
    if(this.checked){

    $(".test").each(function()
        {
        this.checked=true;
            });

    }
    else
        {
        /* this.checked=true; */
        this.checked=false;
        $(".test").each(function(){         
            this.checked=false;
        });
        }
});
```

I am using table in model window.Can anyone guess the problem?

Comment: Is this happening in all browsers? what is your OS?

Comment: Instead of using this, use $(this)

Comment: yes it is happening in all browsers.....Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

When you are using ".each", it's recommended to use a new context in order to copy the current values for using them.

Can you try this ?

```
$("#check_all").click(function(event) {
    var isChecked = this.checked = !this.checked;
    $(".test").each(function(){
        (function (self) {
            self.checked= isChecked;
        })(this);
    });
});
```

Comment: ya but my problem is in getting model window.Options are working inside model window.When button gets clicked model window shows for a moment and then disappears

Comment: What do you mean by "window.Options" ?